# Is there a formula in Google Sheets that recognises if the content of another cell is generated by a formula vs input manually?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Is there a formula/function you know of that recognises if a cell content is generated from another formula and not directly input text/string?

I have a column with a formula that chooses an team member for a task to evenly distribute a task.

This column also has a data validation with the same team members names as choices.

If the team member accepts the task they choose their name from a dropdown box by data validation overwriting the formula so it doesn't change.

I am trying to create a bot (Zapier) that only sends a email when this last step happens, not when the formula selects the team member.
i.e. I was wondering if anyone knows if there is a formula that recognises if the team members are selected by the formula rather than selected by the data validation dropdown.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
=ISFORMULA(A1)
```

[image]

but note that this won't detect input created by arrayformula